# Facebook Android App News Feed Layout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to implement a vertical listview with horizontal scroll on each item just like the facebook newsfeed. Suggested apps can be seen by scrolling to right and some part of next item is also visible.

here is the screenshot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRfM.png

So I am just stuck here and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to write some custom code (which is a pretty good rule of thumb whenever you're trying to do something Facebook did on Android; they do some crazy stuff).

I don't believe you can nest ListViews in Android. There is "ExpandableListView", which lets you expand items to show more, although this isn't quite the same thing.

I would advise to just create a vertical ListView, and have the items be horizontal LinearLayouts that you can inflate yourself. You can also try making them horizontal ScrollViews (although I think this may have the same limitation as using nested ListViews).

Good luck!